# Why would I get PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHORIZATIONOPS using tSQLt when Working at Home?

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr, wait-types, tsqlt

I have an SSDT project containing tSQLt unit tests.

I always find when working at home that publishing this and running all tests (from a post deploy script) is problematic (against both localdb and SQL Server developer edition).

The publish hangs indefinitely and I eventually have to kill visual studio.

The wait type is `PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHORIZATIONOPS` and an example of a statement hung waiting for this (from `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`) is

```
(@r BIT OUTPUT)
SELECT @r = CASE
              WHEN I.Version = I.ClrVersion THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END
FROM   tSQLt.Info() AS I;
```

I also reproduce this by calling

```
SELECT tSQLt.Private::Info()
```

Which is a simple method

```
public static SqlString Info()
{
  return (SqlString) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```

I assume that it is trying to contact the domain controller to establish that I have some permissions or other. I don't get this with other CLR assemblies and so suspect that this may be something to do with TSQLT not being a `SAFE_ACCESS` assembly (permission set is `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`).

Anyone know what's going on here and how I can fix this and work disconnected from my company's network without encountering this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66780/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-martin-smith).

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't going to be connected to the domain all the time, as it is a development instance, change the db owner from a domain account to a local account or a sql account.

Check this great blog out on the subject:

http://andreas-wolter.com/en/where-is-that-preemptive-wait-coming-from/

To summarise the blog post:

- Having a db owner as a domain user causes kerberos ticket granting ticket requests (i.e. sql wants to authenticate using the domain account that is a db owner and kerberos has a thing called ticket granting ticket which lets sql impersonate the db owner)
- If you have high latency (or issues connecting, as in this case) to your domain controller, these calls will be slow
- SQL caches the calls for 10 minutes so these can appear intermittent

ed

Comment: Thanks for sharing that post. The 10 minute time-frame seems to correspond to what @Martin was seeing in testing. Also, while I don't disagree with the idea of changing the db owner (though still no confirmation on it being a domain account), I would still say that if doing that _or_ installing the Asymmetric Key and the associated login equally solve the hanging problem, then I would opt for, at the very least, going with the Asymmetric Key and login, if not doing both. But doing both is probably best.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of testing (details of which can be found in the related [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66780/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-martin-smith)), we have narrowed down the factors that need to be in place for the hanging to happen, but not ultimately what is causing the hanging itself.

What we now know:

1. When *not* connected to the VPN, there is no hanging at all. I suspect that this is due to the OS realizing that it cannot get to the Domain Controller to do any validation, so it falls back to cached credentials.
2. If a test has run successfully (i.e. when *not* connected to the VPN), then the VPN can be connected and the tests continue to run. This suggests that permissions at the SQL Server and/or OS level are being cached. We don't yet have clarity as to where the caching is happening, but we have been able to at least rule out that the permissions are cached with the loaded Assembly (we did this by unloading the App Domain and then re-running the test with the VPN connected and it did not hang).
3. After some amount of time (or so it seems right now due to where we got in the testing), if the VPN is still connected *and* the App Domain is unloaded, then attempting to run a test again will again cause the process to hang. The link posted in @Ed's answer seems to confirm the roughly 10-minute cache timeout that was seen in testing.
4. When the process hangs, it is during a series of external calls to get Windows security info (you can see the stack trace that Martin posted in the discussion at: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40428311#40428311 — click the "(see full text)" link and then look for `sqllang.dll!FVerifyAssemblyPermsForSids`)
5. When the Assembly is set to `SAFE`:

   1. The initial call to the `Info()` TVF succeeds as there are no permissions to check.
   2. But, the [tSQLt.Private_Init](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/blob/master/Source/tSQLt.Private_Init.ssp.sql) stored procedure always attempts to mark the `tSQLtCLR` Assembly as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, in which case (assuming that the Asymmetric Key has *not* been installed):

      1. If `TRUSTWORTHY` is `OFF` then the call in the `Init` proc to the `tSQLt.EnableExternalAccess` proc fails with the "unauthorized for EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE..." error because `TRUSTWORTHY` is not `ON` AND there is no Asymmetric Key. Yet it does not hang because that is a meta-data operation that doesn't need anything from the OS. This should be the call to `ISECManager::FIsAssemblyAuthorized`, which is one step before the `FVerifyAssemblyPermsForSids` step that was noted above.
      2. If `TRUSTWORTHY` is `ON` then the call in the `Init` proc to the `tSQLt.EnableExternalAccess` proc hangs because: a) it passes the "authorization" check, and b) then needs to check the permissions at the OS-level. Hence, it hangs on the `ALTER ASSEMBLY tSQLtCLR WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;` statement.
6. When the Assembly is set to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`:

   1. If `TRUSTWORTHY` is `OFF` then the call in the `Init` proc to the `Info()` TVF fails due to lack of authorization. This is the same issue as we saw above when `TRUSTWORTHY` was `OFF`. The error message is different, but that is only due to the query being in a `TRY...CATCH` construct that has a custom error message (the call to `tSQLt.EnableExternalAccess` is also within a `TRY...CATCH` construct, but that call does not override the error message in the `CATCH` block).
   2. If `TRUSTWORTHY` is `ON` then the call in the `Init` proc to the `Info()` TVF hangs as it reaches out to the OS to get the SID permissions info from the Domain Controller.

What's left to figure out:

1. Where is the caching taking place, and for how long? We have been unloading the App Domain and possibly releasing SQL Server-based authentication caching via: `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL') WITH MARK_IN_USE_FOR_REMOVAL;`. However, we have yet to find a consistent, repeatable length of time. Thus far it appears to be about 9 minutes.
2. If the VPN is connected and the Assembly is loaded into memory, and everything is working, then does the hanging ever occur again?
3. Would this ever happen if the Database had `TRUSTWORTHY OFF`? This can be tested for by waiting until the hung state occurs again, then running `EXEC tSQLt.InstallExternalAccessKey`. Then, set `TRUSTWORTHY OFF` and try again.
   Having the Asymmetric Key and signature-based Login is definitely better than relying on `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, so it is probably best to switch over to that and have `TRUSTWORTHY OFF` regardless.
4. Finally: why does it hang at all? And does any other process hang outside of SQL Server? Or is this an issue that is specific to SQL Server? @Sean Gallardy (in the discussion), suggested that:

   > the reason why the operation takes so long seems to be an issue with contacting the DCs and/or retrieving your information (groups, etc). My guess would be mismatched networking by what you've described where one interface (internet) is somehow picked to lookup this information - which will never complete.